# Issue with file explorer on launcher menu

Tags: nautilus, launcher

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my ASUS X552EA notebook dual-booted with Windows 10.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I click on the "Files" icon in the launcher menu, it opens a new 'Home' window even when there are other active windows.

I want it to show the active windows for me to select the one I want to see, and stop popping-up an absolutely new window.

This doesn't happen if there's already an active 'Home' window. Suggest a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug with Nautilus. Refer to [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1170647) -

You can goto your previously opened window by scrolling over the File icon.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround: Use **Alt+TAB** combination. When you go to Files icon through Alt+Tab windows, you will be able to open your working folder.